# build programs that can be piped in node.js

Tags: unix, node.js

I'd like to make utilities in Node JS which can be used like:

```
node util.js | node util2.js
```

just as you would using say

```
cat * | grep str
```

etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`process.stdin`](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#process.stdin) and [`process.stdout`](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#process.stdout) streams.

Here's an example from those docs:

```
process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.setEncoding('utf8');

process.stdin.on('data', function (chunk) {
  process.stdout.write('data: ' + chunk);
});

process.stdin.on('end', function () {
  process.stdout.write('end');
});
```

Calling `process.stdin.resume()` starts the flow of data from standard input and will keep your program running until stdin is paused or ends.